# Google docs Api Drive no method export

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs

I need to get my doc file in pdf format. I read this article https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads & try to use it, but i don't have method export in my drive object. Can you help me?

[image]

This is my  Pom-file:

```
<google-api-version>1.20.0</google-api-version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>${google-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>${google-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev170-${google-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are referring v3 documentation. And you are using v2 version. There are many difference between these two. Check if there are any version problems. I'm not sure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your version in POM to this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev6-1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thx it works! When i tried drive.files().export(fileId,PDFType).executeAndDownloadTo(bos); i have an error: api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden Insufficient Permission . ///// How fix this? Help,please!

Comment: in ver2 i can share doc on my webPage like this: drive.files().get(fileID).execute().getAlternateLink()); How i can do this in ver3 ??

Comment: Actually I also faced the same problem where I cant get a link back. Th e only way was to go back to v2 for me.